# Outlook Add-in Development : Require Previous Selection Object Of Mailbox

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have a Explorer.SelectionChange event.

Here is a image of outlook inbox :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynQXO.png

I want a previous selection of mail in Explorer.SelectionChange event.
eg :

- Select 'Mail 1'
- Now on selection of 'Mail 2', I want a 'Mail 1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. You need to get the `EntryID` property value of the selected item (for example, in the `SelectionChange` event or at any point of time by using the `Selection` property) and keep it until another item is selected, so you could have it when needed. But don't keep the `MailItem` instance in the code, that is not really a good idea. You should release underlying COM objects in the code instantly and don't hold them where possible. The original item instance can be retrieved when required by using the [GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method which returns a Microsoft Outlook item identified by the specified entry ID (if valid).